# How to use dracut in chroot environment established through SLES15 Rescue boot image?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, suse, rescue-disk, dracut

To fix an unbootable SLES15 system, I booted the Rescue image, mounted the existing system to `/mnt`, and then did `chroot /mnt` (I'm leaving out the details, as those are probably known (or found in [How do you create a chroot environment for OpenSUSE Leap?](https://superuser.com/questions/1677683/how-do-you-create-a-chroot-environment-for-opensuse-leap))).

When trying to rebuild the initrd using `dracut` there is the problem that the kernel being used in the rescue system does not match the kernel found in the `chroot` environment.

For example the output is:

```text
dracut: cannot find module directory /lib/modules/5.3.18.57-default
```

(`5.3.18.57-default` is the kernel from the rescue system; the kernel that does not boot is `5.3.18-150300.59.46-default` for example)

I'm unsure what the correct syntax will be; do I have to spoecify the full path for the initrd and kernel, and if so the "vmlinuz" variant, or the "vmlinux.gz" variant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just recreating the initrd, first find out the kernel(s) installed, using

```shell
rpm -qa kernel-default
```

For example the output might be:

```text
kernel-default-5.3.18-150300.59.43.1.x86_64
kernel-default-5.3.18-150300.59.46.1.x86_64
```

As an alternative you may want to list `/lib/modules` for kernel versions. The result might be:

```shell
> ls -1 /lib/modules/
5.3.18-150300.59.43-default
5.3.18-150300.59.46-default
5.3.18-lp152.72-default
```

Then run the command with an empty first parameter and the kernel version as second parameter, like this (note the changes compared to RPM output):

```shell
dracut '' 5.3.18-150300.59.46-default
```